# Does Superhot Mind Control Delete include the base game?

Tags: superhot, superhot-mind-control-delete

I have heard that owners of the original Superhot got mind control delete free of charge.  Do I need the original superhot to play mind control delete?  Will I miss anything by buying Superhot: Mind Control Delete and not buying Superhot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, considering that the steam page https://store.steampowered.com/app/690040/SUPERHOT_MIND_CONTROL_DELETE/ has a bundle that includes the two of them for an increased price, I'm going to go ahead and guess that it's a standalone expansion that DOES NOT include the base game.

Comment: however I can play it *without* the base game correct?

Comment: ok, I can confirm it does.  Just saw a reddit post where a guy said he'd played mind controll delete but not the original superhot.  Thanks for the help Xendex!

Comment: Np man! Enjoy, it's a very good game :)